# In Linux, when a process is about to be swapped or terminated, what state should its threads be in?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, linux-kernel

By swapped and terminated, I mean, if the process is about to be swapped to a swap space or terminated(*by OOM killer*) to free up memory.

What algorithm does the linux kernel follow?

For instance, Process A needs extra memory and Process B has been chosen to be swapped or killed(*if swap space is already occupied*), but process B still has a blocking thread.

a.) *Does process B gets swapped or killed regardless of the blocking thread?*

b.) *If not, how is this kind of case handled?*

If my example is an unlikely case, any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: What you ask about is called [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) because it is about memory pages, not processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah - you need to read up on paged virtual memory, as suggested by @CL. Processes are not swapped out in their entirety and swapping!=termination.

If the OS needs to terminate a process, either because of a specific API request or because of its OOM algorithm, the OS stops all its threads first.  Blocked threads are easy to 'stop' because they are not running anyway - it's only necessary to change their state to ensure that they are never run again.  Thread/s that are actually running on cores have to be stopped by means of an inter-core comms driver that can hardware-interrupt the cores running the threads.  Once all threads are not running, the resources, including all user-space memory, allocated to the process can be freed and OS thread/process management structs released.  The process then no longer exists.

Comment: Ok. I'll get onto it. Thanks.